# prevent input from submitting when empty (not in form)

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input

I have some rogue input and submit buttons that add new items in a list, I want to prevent them from being submittable when they have nothing in them. They look like this:

```
<input name="name" placeholder="Application Name">
<button type="submit">Add App</button>
```

I have a bunch of them, I was wondering if there was some way I could get all of them not to submit when they have nothing in them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add the required attribute.

```
<input name="name" placeholder="Application Name" required>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Does this work on all browsers and all that?

Comment: yes, all moderns browsers. (use caniuse to see the support, excellent site http://caniuse.com/form-validation). You can also set a pattern, to check per example if the value is a valid mail, a number, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions...

1. Solution is set HTML5 attribute `required`
2. Solution is set function on form, so on submit, function will be processed and `return false;` will prevent submiting:

`<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="checkInputs();return false;" id="form">`

Then you can go through every input:

```
$('#form input').each(function() {
```

And finally, you will check, if is that input `text` type and if is empty:

```
if( type == 'text' && value.length == 0 )
```

Here is [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/wYa33/)

Answer (score 0):

1. 'required' attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.
2. Include the input and button inside a form and validate the form on submit.

HTML Code :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<form name="app_form" id="app">
    <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Application Name">
    <button type="submit">Add App</button>
</form>
```

JS Code :

```
$("#app").submit(function(event) {
    if (!$("#app #name").val()) {
        alert("Please enter Application Name.");
        event.preventDefault();  // this will prevent form submission
});
```